# How can I fix this short delay when I open files in Adobe products?

Tags: windows-explorer, adobe-photoshop, lag, delay

When I do file - open in other programs, such as Word or Chrome, windows file explorer pops up immediately.

When I do it in Adobe Photoshop, Indesign, Illustrator, etc. there's this little 5-second delay. It's not much but it's annoying. Does anyone know of a fix? (don't say bridge)

Comment: @Ramhound it feels like it's the same no matter what, regardless of load. If that's the case, why can't it be removed?

Comment: @Ramhound bringing back this ancient thread, cuz it still drives me nuts, I realized the delay IS variable. If I recently brought up the file - open dialogue,  and then close it and do it again within a few seconds, it appears immediately. If I wait, say, 30 seconds and then do file, open... there's that 5 second lag. I could be crazy but it feels like if the program is minimized or not in focus, it's more likely to lag when I return.